# ProcessCmdKey after closing application

Tags: c#, keypress, keydown, notifyicon

I have this function for the `ProcessCmdKey` that will run some buttons if I will press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.N))
    {
        button4_Click(this, null);
        return true;
    }

    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.A))
    {
        button3_Click(this, null);
        return true;
    }

    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.S))
    {
        label10_Click(this, null);
        return true;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

I have a question, can it be done that after closing the application (not shutdown app), using `Form_Closing` to put the app in `System Icons` using `notifyIcon`, if you will press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (for example), will run the button?

Right now it doesn't work, but can I do this?

Comment: No.  Type "RegisterHotKey" in the search box or a google query.

Answer (score 1):

To set the tray icon see this [guide](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/creating-tray-applications-in-.net-a-practical-guide/).

You can set the icon of your project via Project **Properties > Application > Icon**.

You can hide the window from the task bar like this:

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

This code will stop a form from closing and just hide it (unless windows is shutting down).

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnFormClosing(e);

    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown) 
    {
        return;
    }

    e.Cancel = true;

    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
}
```

This code will give you the tray icon and re-show the form when double clicked.

```
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NotifyIcon trayIcon = new NotifyIcon()
        {
            Icon = new Icon(@"C:\Temp\MyIcon.ico"),
            BalloonTipText = "Open Me!",
            Visible = true
        };

        trayIcon.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(trayIcon_DoubleClick);
    }

    public void trayIcon_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
```

Comment: I know this and i make this, but i want to know if I can use the ProcessCmdKey after I close the app !

Comment: In that case no, at least not without hooking into windows events.